# Android GCM service in another package than the main

Tags: android

I implement GCM for my application. So I tried GCM sample code and made it work. But when I tried to inject the client side code in my app, I was suprised that I must put the GCMIntentService class in the main package otherwise it doesn't work (of course I changed the manifest file by adding `<service android:name=".gcm.GCMIntentService" />` "my_main_package.gcm" is my new package where I put the service.

For information, it works well when I put the service in the main package.

Has anybody an idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](http://dexxtr.com/post/28188228252/rename-or-change-package-of-gcmintentservice-class) is the solution to put **GCMIntentService** in user defined package.

Answer (score 1):

In the class `GCMBroadcastReceiver`

You notice the function :

```
protected String getGCMIntentServiceClassName(Context context) {
    String className = context.getPackageName() +
            DEFAULT_INTENT_SERVICE_CLASS_NAME;
    return className;
}
```

This is the function that is imposing this. You can override/fix the return value.